# Can we get high Bandwidth in Cluster strategy as we get in Star strategy of google nearby connections ?

Tags: google-nearby

We used nearby connection and tried both star and cluster strategy and noticed that in star strategy bandwidth is very high as compared to the bandwidth in cluster strategy.
The network structure which cluster strategy uses, best matches our requirements but we want to have a high bandwidth as we get in star strategy.
If its possible then how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

tldr; You can get high speeds with P2P_CLUSTER but only if both devices are connected to the same router.

The reason P2P_STAR and P2P_POINT_TO_POINT are more restrictive is so that technologies with the same restrictions can be used. P2P_STAR can do everything P2P_CLUSTER can do, but can additionally use Wifi hotspots (and similar technologies, like Wifi Direct). Likewise, P2P_POINT_TO_POINT can do everything P2P_STAR can do, but also with the inclusion of Wifi Aware. It's a tradeoff between flexibility and bandwidth.

As of today, these are the technologies behind each strategy. (Note: We're constantly adding more, and are open to suggestions).

P2P_CLUSTER:

- Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)
- Bluetooth Classic
- Wifi Local Area Network (LAN)

P2P_STAR:

- Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)
- Bluetooth Classic
- Wifi Local Area Network (LAN)
- Wifi Hotspot
- Wifi Direct

P2P_POINT_TO_POINT:

- Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)
- Bluetooth Classic
- Wifi Local Area Network (LAN)
- Wifi Hotspot
- Wifi Direct
- Wifi Aware